# Validation only applies to first email input

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to make sure valid email addresses are entered on [this page](http://getshopaholic.com/demo/).

My problem is that this code only validates the **first** `input` that has `type="email"`.

Is there a workaround for this so that all of them are validated? It certainly doesn't seem to be the case in the plugin's [demo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/).

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.form-inline').validate(
        {
            rules:
            {
                email:
                {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            errorLabelContainer: ".hidden",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element)
            {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<!-- Get notified modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="getNotifiedModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="getNotifiedLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="getNotifiedModal1Label">Sorry, this feature is unavailable in the demo version.</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="p">But why not get notified when the full version of Shopaholic launches?</p>
                <form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
                        <input type="email" name="feature_unavailable_email" class="inputEmail form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Notify me</button>
                </form>
                <div type="hidden" class="hidden" class="p"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Get notified modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="getNotifiedModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="getNotifiedLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="getNotifiedModal2">Get notified when Shopaholic launches!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
                        <input type="email" name="banner_email" class="inputEmail form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Notify me</button>
                </form>
                <div type="hidden" class="hidden" class="p"></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- About modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="aboutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aboutLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="aboutModal">About Shopaholic</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Shopaholic turns your new tab page into a feed of sale items from your favourite clothes stores.</p>
                <p>Simply pick which stores you want to add to your feed, filtering by country and gender, and you're good to go!</p>
                <p id="p">Enter your email address below to get notified when Shopaholic launches.</p>
                <form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
                        <input type="email" name="about_email" class="inputEmail form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Notify me</button>
                </form>
                <div type="hidden" class="hidden" class="p"></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're using an id as your selector might be causing the issue. Instead of `$('#form')` try to use `$('.form-inline')` (the class all your forms seem to be sharing)

EDIT:

Ok so I looked pretty deep into it and here is what you should so.

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('.form-inline').each(function () {
        $(this).validate(
        {
            errorPlacement: function(error, element)
            {
              element.parent("form").next("div.p").html(error);
            }
        });
        $(this).children("input[type=email]").rules("add", {
          required: true,
          email: true
        });
      });
  });
```

I think you should be careful with your naming convention though. Like try to call your error containers something more meaningful like "error-console"

See how instead of calling `.validate()` on one specific element, you have to iterate through all of them using a `.each()` loop.

Also, jQuery Validator use the `name` attribute as a convention when declaring rule...so if you want to use a class you need to call that `.rules("add", {})` in order to make it work

I hope this helped :)

ADDITIONAL EDIT:

Noticed your last form doesn't get validated .. it's because you have your last button set as `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm afraid it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: To clarify, I now have `class="form form-inline"` on each `<form>` and I'm using `$('.form')` in the plugin.

Comment: See my edit above. I tried it locally and it works ... let me know if anything is unclear !

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Is this for my updated code above or what I had before?

Comment: Yes it should work from the very first version you gave us in your original post. Just make sure to swap all your old JS with the one I put !

Comment: That's perfect, thanks very much - and thanks also for the write-up. Lots of good advice to take on board.

Comment: FWIW, you could skip the rules adding line if you instead added classes to your email inputs like `class="inputEmail form-control required email"`.  jQuery Validate will automatically read those into the rules object

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have duplicate `id` since `id` must be unique, so the solution is to replace the duplicated `id` by using class and it should work.

Comment: Oh, does the plugin take `id` or `class`? I thought it was `type`. Which `id` is duplicated?

Comment: No, the plugin is working, just that your HTML markup is invalid so the validation only apply to the first id="inputEmail" that it found on your page

Comment: Thanks for your help - could you take a look at my updated code? It's still giving me problems.